# Pickle AttributeError: Can't get attribute 'EnsembleModel' on <module '__main__' from '<input>'>

Tags: python, python-asyncio, pickle

I've written a custom class to represent an ensemble model, and I want to pickle it for later usage. Here is how I construct the model and save the object using pickle:

```py
import pickle
from typing import Any


class EnsembleModel:
    def __init__(self, estimators: List[Any]):
         return ...

   def fit(self, ...):
         return ...

    def predict(self, ...):
         return ...


ensemble_model = EnsembleModel(estimators=[est_1, est_2, est_3], ...)
ensemble_model.fit(X_train, y_train)

with open("ensemble-model.mdl", "wb") as f:
    pickle.dump(ensemble_model, f)
```

Now, I want to use this binary object **"ensemble-model.mdl"** in another code. I have a more general class, say `MyModel`, to load and represent such models (the reason behind having this class is not the point here). As you can see, this class is responsible for unpickling the EnsembleModel object:

```py
class MyModel:
    model: Any = None
    _probability: float = None
    _predict_method: str = None
    _predict_proba: Any = None

    def __init__(self, model_path: str, model_name: str = 'MyModel', threshold: float = 0.5) -> None:
        with open(model_path, 'rb') as f:
            self.model = pickle.load(f)
        
        ...
```

I keep both classes, `EnsembleModel` and `MyModel`, in a single script in a separate package named `my_package` (*my_package/model.py*) and install this package on the virtual environment on which my main script should be run.

```
my_package:
- __init__.py
- model.py
    -> EnsembleModel
    -> MyModel
- ...
```

This is my main script in which I need to initialize an instance of `MyModel` using the binary object **"ensemble-model.mdl"**:

*main.py*

```py
import asyncio

from my_package.model import EnsembleModel, MyModel


async def main():
    model = MyModel(
        model_name="My Ensemble Model",
        model_path="ensemble-model.mdl",
        threshold=0.5
    )


loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
loop.run_until_complete(main())
loop.close()
```

I get this error when I run *main.py*:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Program Files\JetBrains\PyCharm Community Edition 2022.1.3\plugins\python-ce\helpers\pydev\pydevconsole.py", line 364, in runcode
    coro = func()
  File "<input>", line 2, in <module>
  File "C:\Users\mehdi\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\asyncio\base_events.py", line 616, in run_until_complete
    return future.result()
  File "D:\my_app\my_pipeline\__init__.py", line 108, in main
    MyModel(
  File "D:\my_app\venv\lib\site-packages\my_package\model.py", line 92, in __init__
    self.model = pickle.load(f)
AttributeError: Can't get attribute 'EnsembleModel' on <module '__main__' from '<input>'>
```

It seems that the error is due to the pickling/unpickling process, but I'm not sure how to fix it. Any ideas on how can I fix this error?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's a long-overdue answer, but worth mentioning. I could fix the problem by overriding the `'model'` module as it was imported in the training environment using `sys`.

```py
import asyncio
import sys

import my_package
from my_package.model import EnsembleModel, MyModel

sys.modules['model'] = my_package.model


async def main():
    model = MyModel(
        model_name="My Ensemble Model",
        model_path="ensemble-model.mdl",
        threshold=0.5
    )


loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
loop.run_until_complete(main())
loop.close()
```